# Mysql minimum of sum. Find the student name who is with the minimum of total marks?

Tags: mysql

| students | Subject | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | english | 50 |
| Jack | english | 75 |
| Sam | Maths | 60 |
| Jack | Maths | 35 |
| Sam | Science | 100 |
| Jack | Science | 75 |

How to find the name of the student with the lowest total mark ? And his total marks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select students, sum(Mark) total_marks
from mysterytablename
group by students
order by total_marks
limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you. But now I have two columns the student and his total mark. I need to get the name of the student only.

Comment: ah, you said you wanted total marks too.  then just `select students from mysterytablename group by students order by sum(Mark) limit 1`